# How can I prevent an express route being called twice in a row?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a button that calls a route that publishes information on my website.

The problem is that when users phone lags, they press the button twice before they get redirected to the main page, and then 2 or 3 posts are created.

How could I solve this?

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post("/publishJob", this.state).then(resp => {
      if (resp.data.success) {
        this.setState({
          jobData: ""
        });
        this.props.history.push("/");
      }
    });
  }
```

```
app.post("/publishJob", (req, res) => {
    return database
        .publishJob(
            req.user.id,
            req.body.jobData.data.restname,
            req.body.jobData.data.jobtype,
            req.body.jobData.data.hourpay,
            req.body.jobData.data.typepay,
            req.body.jobData.data.schedule,
            req.body.jobData.data.contact,
            req.body.jobData.data.address,
            req.body.jobData.data.area,
            req.body.jobData.data.phone,
            req.body.jobData.data.extrainfo,
            req.body.jobData.data.urgent,
            req.session.userId
        )
        .then(() => {
            res.json({
                success: true
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Upon click, disable the button until the HTTP request is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Throttle function. This function will only allow one call in an specific time frame, for example, a funcion may only be call once every 2 seconds.

You can find more info about this here: https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

The Throttle function is this:

```
const throttle = (func, limit) => {
  let inThrottle
  return function() {
    const args = arguments
    const context = this
    if (!inThrottle) {
      func.apply(context, args)
      inThrottle = true
      setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit)
    }
  }
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
throttleBtn.addEventListener('click', throttle(function() {
  return console.log('Hey! It is', new Date().toUTCString());
}, 1000));
```